# Reinforcement Learning techniques to use if there is a direct connecction between (state, action) and reward

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I want to build a model. The input state is a combination of different numbers in sequence (Their orders matter to the final result). The effectiveness of such number combination can be computed into a real numbers through continuous and differentiable math formulas. This result is also used to compute a reward for each action.

My actions for each state (number combination) is to select a specific number at a position and change that number to any element from a finite list of numbers.

Are there any suggestions for a good reinforcement technique to solve this problem?

Any bits of help is appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like a combinatorial optimisation problem (e.g. Travelling Salesman Problem) - so your iimmediate reward will be based on some cost or profit from that action in the given state, but that one of the impacts is that the action used is removed from the possible future actions, affecting long-term options significantly?

Comment: If so, it is possible to apply RL techniques to such problems, but usually not the best choice, as many other optimisation techniques are available and competitive. It would help if you clarify what your goal is for applying RL here - if it is to learn more RL, or just to see how well RL does on this problem then using RL makes sense. If it is to try and get the best possible result, it may be very inefficient way to solve your problem.

Comment: Hello Neil, thanks for the reply! My actual goal is to design material structures where each number represents material's properties. The reason why I want to use RL is to test how good is RL on these design problem, maybe it can give good intuitions on how to design shapes and choose materials. There is also another reason. General techniques in computing the efficiency of material combinations could take a very long time to evaluate. Traditional ways of designing structures are not efficient.

Comment: For now, I will allow positions to be accessed for multiple times. Each episode length will be a fixed constant which depends on the length of the 1D sequence.